# How do I invoke a click event with GeckoFx?

Tags: vb.net, geckofx

I can't seem to invoke a click event in GeckoFX in vb.net. Here is my code:

```
Imports Skybound.Gecko
Public Class Form1


    Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()
        Xpcom.Initialize(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/xulrunner")

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        GeckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com")
        Dim Button = New GeckoButtonElement(_webBrowser.Document.getElementById("Search").DomObject)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is that it says I do not have `GeckoButtonElement` class. I followed [this](http://www.ultimateprogrammingtutorials.info/2012/12/how-to-make-web-browse-using-geckofx-on.html) tutorial.

Can someone help me get this button to click in another way? Or is there something else I have to do?

Side question: is there a package with the latest geckofx + xulrunner for download somewhere? I can't seem to find anything newer than what was offered in the tutorial above (which is from 2012).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim button As Gecko.DOM.GeckoButtonElement = TryCast(_webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("Search"), Gecko.DOM.GeckoButtonElement)
If button IsNot Nothing Then
    button.Click()
End If
```

Newer versions of GeckoFx available on https://bitbucket.org/geckofx

Latest version is GeckoFx 29.0 (https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0/downloads).

Comment: how do I specify the imports? `imports Skybound.Gecko` doesn't seem to work. Also, do I extract all the zip contents into the `bin\debug`folder?

Comment: If you use Geckofx 4.0 or newer: `Imports Gecko`. You will also want to add references to all dll's from the zip archive, and extract all xulrunner files into the `bin\debug` folder'. The XulRunner version must be the same as the Geckofx version.